# Logo feedback request

Tags: logo, critique, branding

[image: CPR Education logo variants]

I'm hoping the community might help resolve a few concerns regarding the above logos.

1. Is the font in logo 'B' too thin or small (for the word *Education*)?
2. Does the red outline in logo 'A' make reading it harder on the eyes?
3. Does the brighter blue of 'logo A' make it more eye-catching?
4. Logo 'A' has an accurate ECG rhythm, while 'B' is stylized, but inaccurate. Does this accuracy matter in regard to logo creation?
5. The ECG line in 'B' is centered.  Is this balance generally considered more effective in logo design/branding?

I would love to know if there are studies or science to help answer or guide replies, but I value your personal opinions too.   Many thanks!

Comment: 1. No, it looks correct. 2. Yes. 3. Yes. 4. No. 5. Opinion, centered makes it too balanced. Dynamic is more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably lose the red, use the ECG from the left image but stick the colors in the right image.

You could merely reverse the ECG path from the star of life symbol...

[image]

If you want the red, then *use the red* make it more visually prominent rather than just thin, wispy lines.

Overall, it's not a very unique symbol other than colors. ([1](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Ju3rU%2BAeL._SX342_.jpg), [2](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4d/2d/5f/4d2d5f8fa99bf1f7e49fb30f59bf37fe.jpg), [3](https://img1.etsystatic.com/172/1/14091166/il_340x270.1237904223_n562.jpg)) But then, given the industry, there's value in using familiar imagery.

I'd also address the type. I dislike logos that are merely someone setting a font and forgetting it. The type should be as "designed" as any symbol. This is *especially* true since the symbology is fairly commonplace. The varying weights is a step in the right direction though. If nothing else, address the kerning between the C, P, and R.

Comment: “Get rid of the rid” was the first thing I thought, too. Way too jarring, hurts my eyes. Too many colours in general: no need for the snowflake to be blue, the line red, and the text teal. Just stick to the light blue for the snowflake, no lines (as in your top examples here), and the same light blue—with better attention to font detail—for the text.

Comment: Metis, thank you for your thoughts on this.  When you say "address the kerning between the C, P, and R", are you thinking wider, or closer together?

Comment: Also, you're right that the ECG symbol isn't unique, but the simple and stylized one in 'B' is.  Do you prefer that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the font in logo 'B' too thin or small (for the word Education)?

no

> Does the red outline in logo 'A' make reading it harder on the eyes?

Yes. Saturated blue and saturated red do not work well together. They can cause a lot of eye strain. This will also be harder to print.

> Does the brighter blue of 'logo A' make it more eye-catching?

No. It makes it more jarring and harder on the eyes.

> Logo 'A' has an accurate ECG rhythm, while 'B' is stylized, but inaccurate. Does this accuracy matter in regard to logo creation?

No. Logos aren't literal.

> The ECG line in 'B' is centered. Is this balance generally considered more effective in logo design/branding?

There's no rule here. You do what works for the particular logo you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

1) NO; the whitespace actually draws my eyes towards "education."

2) YES; I also don't see any purpose for the red outline.

3) NO; not necessarily. There's psychology in using colors for sure, but a great logo is recognizable from a galloping and also if it's display in monochrome.

4) NO; unless the community that your belongs to would be offended by the inaccuracy (perhaps they're too pedantic?).

5) I agree with @Webstarian that "Dynamic is more interesting" in the end I always remember to metabalance (mind to balance [v] the balance [n]).

Trust your gut.

Answer (score 0):

Short opinion:

Continue with B. If you remove its ECG curve and add the curve from A but in B's color, B will be better in all of your five areas.

I mean this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinion based question. I'll give you my answer but it is only my personal opinion. 1 No, 2 Yes, 3 Yes, 4 No, 5 Yes, but balance doesn't have to be symmetrical or centred only, there are other ways and methods to go about balancing designs, such as the Golden ratio, Rule of Thirds, etc.

I feel there is no definitive answer for these kind of questions, since so much depends on individual taste. However, I think you need to simplify the logo a little more. For me, simple logos with less fussy detail often work best. Also, I'm not sure if I like the red and blue together, they kind of clash - again only my opinion!